# Django Haystack add additional input to search

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I've a haystack search currently works well searching on the following model:

```
class AdminEntry(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    number_entries = models.IntegerField(max_length=3,  null=True)
```

My `search_indexes.py`:

```
class AdminEntryIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    author = CharField(model_attr='product__author')
    title = CharField(model_attr='product__title')
    desc = CharField(model_attr='product__desc')

    def get_queryset(self):
        return AdminEntry.objects.all()

site.register(AdminEntry, AdminEntryIndex)
```

but now I want to add additional search parameter in dropdown in my search form with 2 values `['Admin', 'Staff']` since I've added another model:

```
class StaffEntry(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    number_entries = models.IntegerField(max_length=3,  null=True)
```

I want to my search to search on `StaffEntry` if the dropdown selected is 'Staff', and `AdminEntry` is 'Admin' is selected. Can someone help me on how to achieve this using Haystack with Whoosh? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is the ModelSearchForm:

http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views_and_forms.html#modelsearchform

use this instead of the default SearchForm, and you'll get checkboxes for each indexed model. If you extend the form you'll be able to change it to a select instead of checkboxes.

See http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views_and_forms.html#views for information on how to use your custom form in the view.

Answer (score 0):

**forms.py**

class Search(SearchForm):

```
         OPTIONS = [
                ('staff','Staff'),
                ('admin','Admin')
               ]

          option = forms.ChoiceField(
                    widget=forms.Select(
                        attrs={'class':'cd-select','id':'cd-dropdown'}),
                        label='',
                        choices=OPTIONS,
                        )
         def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
             super(Search, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
             self.initial['option'] = 'staff'
             self.fields['q'].label = ''



        def search(self):
            if not self.is_valid():
                 return self.no_query_found()
            if not self.cleaned_data.get('q'):
                 return self.no_query_found()
            sqs = self.searchqueryset.auto_query(self.cleaned_data['q'])

            if self.cleaned_data['option'] == 'staff':
                 sqs = SearchQuerySet().auto_query(self.cleaned_data['q']).models(Staff)
            elif self.cleaned_data['option'] == 'admin':
                 sqs = SearchQuerySet().auto_query(self.cleaned_data['q']).models(Admin)
            if self.load_all:
                 sqs = sqs.load_all()
            return sqs
```